# How to unit test methods that are void and do not take any parameters?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, return, void

Methods like selectBoardSize (int x, int y). Returns a new board size.

This method has values and has parameters that can be unit-tested and compared in a project.

What about methods that are void? Like void playSound. This method only plays the sound of the game. Does not take any values and does not return anything. How should we write a unit test for methods like these?

Comment: What does the method _do_? Test that. Does it set some value on the `object`? Check that the value is set. Does it play a sound using a `Clip`? [Mock](https://blog.42.nl/articles/mockito-powermock-vs-jmockit/) the `clip` and check that `start()` is called.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I see. So i should write unit tests for the objects that I am using in my playSound method?

Comment: Well, obviously that should be unit tested too. But you should use the [IOC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) pattern to inject that into your other class, exactly so that you can mock it when needed.

Comment: @SishuanKen [This Q&A]( http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/135886/44705)

Comment: "There are many things "on the edges" of most systems that cannot adequately be unit tested. For example, anything that produces graphics or sound. For these kinds of systems, you are probably best off with manual testing." Maybe this is true? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @SishuanKen There is no way to answer the question "did the sound play?" with 100% certainty without actually hearing the sound play. You can get very close by monitoring API events, but to check that the sound was actually audible to someone running the program you need a separate microphone etc.

Answer (score 7):

Depending on its purpose, a `void` parameterless methods must do a combination of these things:

- **Change the state of your object** - one or more variables of your object will change their values after the call
- **Produce some side effect** - There method would perform some input or output, or make some other changes to the environment
- **Do nothing or throw an exception** - the method may perform some validation, and either remain quiet or throw an exception

You should structure your unit test in such a way as to verify that the desired change has happened.

Answer (score 0):

First, to cover some terminology, testing for audio or graphical output technically is an **integration test** since it involves the combination of your code and some hardware device.  That being said, the [JUnit documentation](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/faq/faq.htm#tests_4) discusses a general method for dealing with `void` methods.  You can test for a *side-effect* to calling your `void` method.  Instead of comparing the output of `playSound()` against a control value, you can compare the *state* of something which was affected by calling the method.

```
InputStream is = new InputStream("yourMusic.mp3");
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
playSound(bis);               // play the sound using the input stream
assertEquals(-1, bis.read()); // make sure entire sound has been played
```